# How to transform Article from URL to text in Android App

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build an app that takes the URL of an article and transforms the article from that URL into a readable text. Until now i managed to take the entire HTML from that URL, but I was wondering how can I take only the text of the article. 
I am using [newsapi.org](https://newsapi.org/) to take the URL. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try parsing only sections of the DOM? Did you see if there are any open source libraries that help with this task?

Comment: I tried to find any open source library to help me, but I haven't found anything yet. If you could help me with something, it would be amazing.

Comment: I am trying to create something like Safari's Reader Mode. I only want the important parts of the html.

Comment: Sounds good. You're going to have to take a library like the one listed in the duplicate, parse the HTML, and extract the parts of the DOM you want to keep. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I am going to try it and tell you if it works.

Comment: You should indicate in the UI that this question is a duplicate before you go.